# Two processes using the same port?

Tags: sockets, http, tcp

So I was looking into what port dropbox uses on my computer and tried to see what would happen if i created a new http server on that port. Surprisingly it worked. So both dropbox and my http server were running on the same port, but the incoming requests were routed to the different application depending on the source address.

```
lsof -i tcp:51311

COMMAND  PID           USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME

Dropbox 3811 user   18u  IPv4 0xdedc291239eb197f      0t0  TCP 172.20.10.2:51311->108.160.163.34:http (ESTABLISHED)

node    3984 user   11u  IPv4 0xdedc29123b1494cf      0t0  TCP *:51311 (LISTEN)
```

I am wondering how this works. I thought the os would refuse the bind my http server since the port was already alloted to dropbox but to my surprise it worked. Anyone thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TCP sockets match against the 4-tuple (source-ip, source-port, destination-ip, destination-port). As long as all four of them don't clash, you can have port reuse.

As long as your daemon doesn't receive a connection from `108.160.163.34:80` your stack can handle it. If the server `108.160.163.34` is well-behaved it won't let an application initiate a connection to your socket (`172.20.10.2:51311`) with 80 as source port. (`bind()` should fail with `Address already in use`).

If it isn't well behaved, the existing dropbox connection will receive an unexpected packet (wrong sequence number space) and your stack will `RST` it.

Answer (score 1):

The HTTP port being used by Dropbox is at 108.160.263.34, not your local host.

Port 51311 is being used as one outbound port and one listening port. Not 'two services running on the same port'. Otherwise there would be two LISTENING lines.

Comment: OP is talking about port 51311 on his box.

Comment: Port 51311 is being used as one outbound port and one listening port. Not 'two services running on the same port'. Otherwise there would be two LISTENING lines.

Comment: From my reading, I think he meant to say "two processes using same port" instead.

Comment: Anything is possible. i'm addressing the question he actually asked.